# Display Json from Node.js in Chart.js with React

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, chart.js

Im getting a JSON Object from mysql databse with Node.js. Than I want to display it in real time with Chart.js and React but first things first. For getting the json this is my code: (`script.js`)

```
const mysql=require('mysql')
const express=require('express')
var app=express();

var mysqlConnection=mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password:'',
    database:'sampledb'
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{

    if(!err){
        console.log('DB Connection sucessful');
    }else{
        console.log('DB Connection failed \n Error:' +JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));

    }
});


app.listen(3001,()=>console.log('Express server is running at port: 3001'));


//Get all
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM mysampletable', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err){
            res.send(rows);//this gives me my JSON
            console.log(rows);
        }

        else
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```

So i dont understand how I can get the json object in realtime that I can display it with chart.js and React. For example I got an small Code snippet for displayingthe data as the following (`App.js`):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Chart from './components/Chart'


class App extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            chartData:{

            }
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getchartData();
    }


    getchartData = () => {
        // Make request to the node backend. You might need to enable CORS in the express app.
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((jsonarray) => {
                var labels = jsonarray.map(function(e) {
                    return e.Name;
                });
                var data = jsonarray.map(function(e) {
                    return e.Value;
                });

                console.log(labels,data);

                this.setState({
                    chartData:{
                        labels:labels,
                        datasets:[
                            {
                                label:'Popuplation',

                                data:data
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            });
    };   

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">

                    <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} location="Test" legendPosition="bottom"/>
                </header>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This line `console.log(labels,data);` gives the following output in the webbrowser(Firefox console):

```
Array(4) [ "Test", "Testtwo", "Test", "Testtwo" ]
 Array(4) [ 5, 10, 5, 10 ]
```

On Microsoft Edge I get the following response:

```
Test,Testtwo,Test,Testtwo 5,10,5,10
```

For completness my working Chart.js witch displays the Chart:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';


class Chart extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            chartData:props.chartData
        }
    }

    static defaultProps={
        displayTitle:true,
        displayLegend:true,
        legendPosition:'right',
        location:'City'


    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="Chart">

                <Line
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                    options={{
                        title:{
                            display:this.props.displayTitle,
                            text: 'Largest Cities in ' + this.props.location,
                            fontsize:25
                        },
                        legend:{
                            display:this.props.displayLegend,
                            position:this.props.legendPosition
                        }

                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Chart;
```

Thankful for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fetch` to make an api call to the backend.

```
getchartData = () => {
    // Make request to the node backend. You might need to enable CORS in the express app.
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/") 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((jsonarray) => {
        var labels = jsonarray.map(function(e) {
            return e.Name;
        });
        var data = jsonarray.map(function(e) {
            return e.Value;
        });

        this.setState({
            chartData:{
                labels:labels,
                datasets:[
                    {
                        label:'Popuplation',

                        data:data
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Also you can remove the state in `Chart.js` as it is unnecessary and use props directly.

```
render() {
        return(
            <div className="Chart">

                <Line
                    data={this.props.chartData}


                ...
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zbs4fo) example

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I copied your code and inserted my things from `this.setState({    }); ` but it I get an error saying: Unexcepted token, excepted ";". I think there is a missing ')' from `.then((jsonarray) => {`. Where I have to close the ) or am I wrong?

Comment: @Botlobblob yes, you are supposed to complete that setState. I just answered on how to make an api call. I have edited the answer to include the `setState` statement as well.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. I copied the code and after that I opened Git Bash `npm start` but I don´t get any data. What do I wrong?  It opens `localhost:3000` and displays a Chart.js line but without any data.

Comment: If I start the code like I mentioned in the comment before I dont get the console.logs: `Express server is running at port: 3000` and `DB Connection sucessful`

Comment: Check if there is any error message in the console. If react app is running on port 3000, Express app should run at some other port, maybe 3001. And you should send the api request from `fetch` to that url.

Comment: Hey, I changed `app.listen(3001,()=>console.log('Express server is running at port: 3001'));` and `fetch("http://localhost:3001/")`. But if I start Git Bash `npm start` I dont get any console output from `script.js` for example `Express server is running at port: 3001')`. So I think the script.js is not called.

Comment: Yeah that worked but my Chart.js line is on `localhost:3000`. How can I see this without kill the `node script.js`command an call `npm start` ? I tried to open another git bash and called `npm start` but it dosnt display any data.

Comment: You cannot run two programs in the same port. Let's say you run react app on port 3000 and express app on 3001. Also make sure first you start the express app. Then the react app. Check the console / network tab in browser developer tab to see if there is an error

Comment: Yeah your are right. I opened the web console and it told me the error you mentioned above that i need to `enable CORS`. So I fixed it. Now it told me `Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.`. But i think this couldn´t be the reason thats not working because it´s only a warning. On my code I added an output to see if the array is getting to the App.js: `.then((jsonarray) => {

                console.log(jsonarray);

                var labels = jsonarray.map(function(e) {
                    return e.Name;
                });`

Comment: The Output on the webconsole is: `0: Object { Name: "Test", Value: 5 }
​
1: Object { Name: "Testtwo", Value: 10 }
​
2: Object { Name: "Test", Value: 5 }
​
3: Object { Name: "Testtwo", Value: 10 }`. So the error has to be the `componentWillMount ` ?

Comment: @Botlobblob Use `componentDidMount` life cycle method instead of `componentWillMount`. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Nice. This cleared the Warning but my data is still not displayed. Mh.. the console.log mentioned in my comment before gives me `Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]` and if I say display more it is like mentioned above `0: Object { Name: "Test", Value: 5 }
​
1: Object { Name: "Testtwo", Value: 10 }
​
2: Object { Name: "Test", Value: 5 }
​
3: Object { Name: "Testtwo", Value: 10 }
​
length: 4`. Is somethin wrong with the data or the form that it can´t be displayed? By now thank you so much for your help

Comment: I edited the question to my current status. I don´t get the mistake I made.

Comment: @Botlobblob Oh! you are using another state in `Chart.js` for displaying which is unnecessary and it is not at all updated. Use props directly instead.` <Line
                    data={this.props.chartData} .....` I have added a working example also.

Comment: Another question... if I inserted a new value in my database I had to reload the site... Is there a way thats this is working without manually reloading the side?

Comment: There are few options like polling the backend for updated data each second or pub sub mechanism where the client will get notified when data changes in the server, or simple websocket connection where updated data will be pushed to the connected clients from the server. Please do mark the answer as accepted if it did help you solve the original question.